# How to change CTE coding to INLINE view? Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, inline, common-table-expression

My system doesn't allow CTE in coding and the first word has to always be SELECT.

Could someone explain (ideally in a Oracle SQL for dummies format) how I would go about changing code written with CTE into INLINE code?

As an example of CTE code:

```
   WITH table1
   AS (SELECT enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number,
            enquiry_status_log.enquiry_log_number,
            follow_up.follow_up_name,
            enquiry_status_log.follow_up_date,
            RANK ()
            OVER (PARTITION BY enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number
                  ORDER BY enquiry_status_log.enquiry_log_number DESC)
               rn
       FROM enquiry_status_log
            JOIN follow_up
               ON enquiry_status_log.follow_up_code =
                     follow_up.follow_up_code)
SELECT enquiry_number,
     enquiry_log_number,
     follow_up_name,
     follow_up_date
FROM table1
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY enquiry_number, enquiry_log_number
```

How would I write this (please, VERY easy to understand) so that SELECT would be the first word in the code and CTE wasn't used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CTE is used only once in your query, so you can simply turn it to a subquery:

```
SELECT enquiry_number,
     enquiry_log_number,
     follow_up_name,
     follow_up_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        e.enquiry_number,
        e.enquiry_log_number,
        f.follow_up_name,
        e.follow_up_date,
        RANK () OVER (
            PARTITION BY e.enquiry_number
            ORDER BY e.enquiry_log_number DESC
        ) rn
       FROM enquiry_status_log e
        JOIN follow_up f ON e.follow_up_code = f.follow_up_code
    ) table1
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY enquiry_number, enquiry_log_number
```

Note: table aliases make the query shorter and easier to read. I modified you query to use them.

Also, it is *possible* that your query could be rewritten to use a correlated subquery for filtering instead of `rank()`. In Oracle, this could lead to better performance:

```
SELECT 
    e.enquiry_number,
    e.enquiry_log_number,
    f.follow_up_name,
    e.follow_up_date
FROM enquiry_status_log e
JOIN follow_up f ON e.follow_up_code = f.follow_up_code
WHERE e.enquiry_log_number = (
    SELECT MAX(enquiry_log_number)
    FROM enquiry_status_log e1
    WHERE e.enquiry_number = e1.enquiry_number
)
ORDER BY e.enquiry_number, e.enquiry_log_number
```

Comment: Thank you - so anything from the AS to the FROM needs to go within brackets in a FROM section?

Comment: @RobMorris: yes exactly. Also you might want to give a shot to the second query, which is simpler and might give equivalent results (this needs to be tested though).